# Точки останова в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2019

Как посмотреть данные в переменных с помощью точки останова?
Раньше в окне снизу показывались, а сейчас не могу найти.

Comment: В меню вид поищи в окнах watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё же я хотел увидеть вот такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во время отладки можно ввести слово "Локальные" в поиск на верхней панели VS, либо сочетание клавиш: Ctrl+Alt+V, L

Answer (score 1):

Когда я последний раз пользовался Visual Studio, ставишь поинт и когда процесс останавливается, наводишь на переменную или метод и видишь, что там происходит. Если не ошибаюсь.